# OS X (Yosemite) auto login on remote desktop

Tags: login, mac, vnc

I have configured my VNC server on my iMac using the "Share Desktop" feature. I'm trying to access with Ubuntu default's client Remmina. I'm currently trying to access as a view-only client but it's not possible since whenever I connect using remmina (asks for my username/password) it displays my iMac's login screen where I need to select my user and input my password.

Is there any way login automatically on each connection?

Comment: To clarify are you connecting with the OS X Screen Sharing application which can be found under `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Screen\ Sharing.app`?

Comment: No, im using the desktop sharing option under Share under system preferences.